# Bash convert data in to csv

Tags: string, csv, awk, sed, data-conversion

I have some data coming to me from an API call, 2 same lines below.

```
"serialNumber=5086", "deviceName=CSECHO002", "address=1.1.1.3", "deviceType=Network Switch", "parentNames, "tag1 (Site)=East Coast", "tag2 (Location)=DATA CENTRE 2", "tag3 (Rack)=RACK 06", "tag4 (Tag 4)=", "tag5 (Tag 5)=Xtraction", "locationName=GOLLZDGP01:Gold Coast DGEX", "dgeName=GOLLZDGP01", "isSuspended=false", "clearOnOk=false", "smartNotify=true", "showOnSummary=true", "accountSerialNumber=49", "accountName=Echo Ent", "isReadOnly=false", "isImported=false", "model=Nexus7000 C7010 (10 Slot) Chassis", "vendor=Cisco Systems", "rediscoveryEnabled=true", "rediscoveryFrequency=1440", "rediscoveryNewTestsAction=updateAndLog", "rediscoveryUpdatedTestsAction=updateAndLog", "rediscoveryDeletedTestsAction=logOnly", "applicationProfiles=none", "configBackupEnabled=true", "configBackupFrequency=1440", "processCollectionEnabled=false", "flapPreventionWaitCycles=-1", "comment=Cisco Nexus 7000 Series Switches
"serialNumber=5091", "deviceName=CSECHO001", "address=1.1.1.2", "deviceType=Network Switch", "parentNames, "tag1 (Site)=East Coast", "tag2 (Location)=DATA CENTRE", "tag3 (Rack)=RACK B5", "tag4 (Tag 4)=", "tag5 (Tag 5)=Xtraction", "locationName=GOLLZDGP01:Gold Coast DGEX", "dgeName=GOLLZDGP01", "isSuspended=false", "clearOnOk=false", "smartNotify=true", "showOnSummary=true", "accountSerialNumber=49", "accountName=Echo Ent", "isReadOnly=false", "isImported=false", "model=Nexus7000 C7010 (10 Slot) Chassis", "vendor=Cisco Systems", "rediscoveryEnabled=true", "rediscoveryFrequency=1440", "rediscoveryNewTestsAction=updateAndLog", "rediscoveryUpdatedTestsAction=updateAndLog", "rediscoveryDeletedTestsAction=logOnly", "applicationProfiles=none", "configBackupEnabled=true", "configBackupFrequency=1440", "processCollectionEnabled=false", "flapPreventionWaitCycles=0", "comment=Cisco Nexus 7000 Series Switches
```

How can I just get the data in csv format, with out the field names?

I've got this far but its getting messy, and Im sure there is a simple way to just grab strings between the = and the next double quote or similar.

```
>     for LINE in $(/usr/bin/curl -b cookie_det -s --insecure 'https://my.url.com/api/rest/command/device.list?deviceName=CS*'); do
> echo $LINE | sed 's/,/\n/g' | awk -F"=" '{ print $2}'| sed 's/"//g' ;
> echo -------; ; done
```

Comment: 2 sample lines sorry

Comment: Managed to get this working too:  `code  for LINE in $(/usr/bin/curl -b cookie_det -s --insecure 'https://traverse.casino.internal/api/rest/command/device.list?deviceName=AUGOLCS*'); do echo $LINE | sed 's/,/\n/g' | awk -F"=" '{ print $2}'| sed 's/"//g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g' ; echo; done `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the pattern is exactly as specified above, you could use submatching in a sed replace to get what you need:

```
sed -E 's/"[^=]*=([^"]*)("|$)/\1/g'
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that works on my sample data. Ill run it on the full output to test.

Comment: The first place it will fall down is with any escaped double-quotes, and probably anything multiline. If you find a counterexample, reply with it and I'd love to help.

Comment: You can avoid the escaping if you read from a file or directly from the API call.

Answer (score 0):

Input: foo.txt

```
"serialNumber=5086", "deviceName=CSECHO002", "address=1.1.1.3", "deviceType=Network Switch", "parentNames, "tag1 (Site)=East Coast", "tag2 (Location)=DATA CENTRE 2", "tag3 (Rack)=RACK 06", "tag4 (Tag 4)=", "tag5 (Tag 5)=Xtraction", "locationName=GOLLZDGP01:Gold Coast DGEX", "dgeName=GOLLZDGP01", "isSuspended=false", "clearOnOk=false", "smartNotify=true", "showOnSummary=true", "accountSerialNumber=49", "accountName=Echo Ent", "isReadOnly=false", "isImported=false", "model=Nexus7000 C7010 (10 Slot) Chassis", "vendor=Cisco Systems", "rediscoveryEnabled=true", "rediscoveryFrequency=1440", "rediscoveryNewTestsAction=updateAndLog", "rediscoveryUpdatedTestsAction=updateAndLog", "rediscoveryDeletedTestsAction=logOnly", "applicationProfiles=none", "configBackupEnabled=true", "configBackupFrequency=1440", "processCollectionEnabled=false", "flapPreventionWaitCycles=-1", "comment=Cisco Nexus 7000 Series Switches
"serialNumber=5091", "deviceName=CSECHO001", "address=1.1.1.2", "deviceType=Network Switch", "parentNames, "tag1 (Site)=East Coast", "tag2 (Location)=DATA CENTRE", "tag3 (Rack)=RACK B5", "tag4 (Tag 4)=", "tag5 (Tag 5)=Xtraction", "locationName=GOLLZDGP01:Gold Coast DGEX", "dgeName=GOLLZDGP01", "isSuspended=false", "clearOnOk=false", "smartNotify=true", "showOnSummary=true", "accountSerialNumber=49", "accountName=Echo Ent", "isReadOnly=false", "isImported=false", "model=Nexus7000 C7010 (10 Slot) Chassis", "vendor=Cisco Systems", "rediscoveryEnabled=true", "rediscoveryFrequency=1440", "rediscoveryNewTestsAction=updateAndLog", "rediscoveryUpdatedTestsAction=updateAndLog", "rediscoveryDeletedTestsAction=logOnly", "applicationProfiles=none", "configBackupEnabled=true", "configBackupFrequency=1440", "processCollectionEnabled=false", "flapPreventionWaitCycles=0", "comment=Cisco Nexus 7000 Series Switches
```

foo.sh

```
while read -r line ; do
    echo $line | sed -e 's/"[^=]*=\([^"]*\)"/"\1"/g'
done < foo.txt
```

Output:

```
"5086", "CSECHO002", "1.1.1.3", "Network Switch", "East Coast", "DATA CENTRE 2", "RACK 06", "", "Xtraction", "GOLLZDGP01:Gold Coast DGEX", "GOLLZDGP01", "false", "false", "true", "true", "49", "Echo Ent", "false", "false", "Nexus7000 C7010 (10 Slot) Chassis", "Cisco Systems", "true", "1440", "updateAndLog", "updateAndLog", "logOnly", "none", "true", "1440", "false", "-1", "Cisco Nexus 7000 Series Switches"
"5091", "CSECHO001", "1.1.1.2", "Network Switch", "East Coast", "DATA CENTRE", "RACK B5", "", "Xtraction", "GOLLZDGP01:Gold Coast DGEX", "GOLLZDGP01", "false", "false", "true", "true", "49", "Echo Ent", "false", "false", "Nexus7000 C7010 (10 Slot) Chassis", "Cisco Systems", "true", "1440", "updateAndLog", "updateAndLog", "logOnly", "none", "true", "1440", "false", "0", "Cisco Nexus 7000 Series Switches"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also try to achieve it by using `awk`,

```
$ awk -F'", ' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){gsub(/".*=/,"",$i);printf "\"%s\"%s",$i,(i==NF)?"\n":", "}}' foo.txt 
"5086", "CSECHO002", "1.1.1.3", "Network Switch", "East Coast", "DATA CENTRE 2", "RACK 06", "", "Xtraction", "GOLLZDGP01:Gold Coast DGEX", "GOLLZDGP01", "false", "false", "true", "true", "49", "Echo Ent", "false", "false", "Nexus7000 C7010 (10 Slot) Chassis", "Cisco Systems", "true", "1440", "updateAndLog", "updateAndLog", "logOnly", "none", "true", "1440", "false", "-1", "Cisco Nexus 7000 Series Switches"
"5091", "CSECHO001", "1.1.1.2", "Network Switch", "East Coast", "DATA CENTRE", "RACK B5", "", "Xtraction", "GOLLZDGP01:Gold Coast DGEX", "GOLLZDGP01", "false", "false", "true", "true", "49", "Echo Ent", "false", "false", "Nexus7000 C7010 (10 Slot) Chassis", "Cisco Systems", "true", "1440", "updateAndLog", "updateAndLog", "logOnly", "none", "true", "1440", "false", "0", "Cisco Nexus 7000 Series Switches"
```

Brief explanation,

1. `-F'", '`: set the field separator as `",` (the space is the last digit)
2. `gsub(/".*=/,"",$i`): eliminate all matched pattern in each field